# Is there any rpg language plugin for Sublime Text 2?

Tags: sublimetext2, rpgle, rpg

Is there any plugin to view rpg, rpgle or database files (obtained from as-400 server) in highlighted syntax in Sublime text 2 editor.
Also, are there any good plugin projects available that I can modify to create my own plugin and share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick Google search is enough to convince me that there is no such language binding available. If you want to create your own, I think [this](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/syntaxdefs.html) would be a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

My colleague Pete Smith has written a simple but very usable [plugin](https://github.com/PeteStanSmith/SublimeForRPG) for Sublime Text 3 extending the existing Icebreak language definition, although I will warn you that it is functionally quite specific to our development environment - we use [SEE/Change](http://thenon.net/seechange/). I am certain that PRs are welcome!